# Using MassTransit to route to development environment

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

I'm trying in using MassTransit (with Azure ServiceBus) to connect two processes, but also allow for either one of these services to be developed from a local environment and have the routing happen to that local environment, instead.

So the non-development data flow would be:

1. ServiceA (in EnvironmentA) sends EventA to ServiceB (in EnvironmentA)
2. ServiceB (in EnvironmentA) sends EventB to ServiceA (in EnvironmentA)

Then when a developer wants to debug on ServiceA, the data flow changes to this:

1. ServiceA (in **EnvironmentB**) sends EventA to ServiceB (in EnvironmentA)
2. ServiceB (in EnvironmentA) sends EventB to ServiceA (in **EnvironmentB**)

There are lots of ways to set this up, but I'm assuming that somebody already has this problem solved.

For example, instead of having one Subscription, you could have two Subscriptions, one for each environment, and each with a Subscription Rule that looks for a particular value in the "To" property.  When ServiceA sends a message, it specificies a "ReplyTo" property in the message, then ServiceB monitors the "ReplyTo" and puts it into the "To" property in the return message. 
 However, I wouldn't know how to set up this Subscription rule from MassTransit.

1. ServiceA (in EnvironmentB) sends EventA (**with "ReplyTo=EnvironmentB"**) to ServiceB (in EnvironmentA)
2. ServiceB (in EnvironmentA) sends EventB (**with "To=EnvironmentB"**) to ServiceA (in EnvironmentB)

Comment: With request/response, you can do this, as the response will be sent to the requestor. With more complex systems, that might not be enough. There are designs for future work around routing and environments, but that work hasn't even started yet: https://gist.github.com/phatboyg/0254dd05dea1f51d919cea320ec59518#environment-versioning

Comment: I tried request/response, but that just sends it back to *any* endpoint listening to a particular event type.  That means that both EnvironmentA an EnvironmentB will handle it.  The desired behavior is that *only* EnvironmentB handles it because you're trying to develop/debug something.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson is there a way in the request/response pattern that allows you to specify sending the "response" back to the exact bus that the "request" came from?

Comment: The request client and service would need to be on the same service bus namespace, all requests sent include a ResponseAddress in the headers by default, to which the response is sent.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson The ResponseAddress is null.  Inside the Request Consumer, I do see a context.SourceAddress, but that won't work. Why would the ResponseAddress be null?

Comment: Are you using the request client: http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/request-response.html

Comment: @ChrisPatterson, no I'm doing it from inside an IConsumer, and using the context.RespondAsync() as shown in the first example on that page.  But the ResponseAddress is null inside the Consume() method.

Comment: From the sending-side of the conversation, you should use the request client, which sets the RequestId and ResponseAddress.